# Why when using String.contains in a Linq expression, are parentheses not required?

Tags: c#, linq

I was reading a solution on a coding exercise site and it was for determining if a sentence is a pangram and I came across this solution:

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".All(input.ToLower().Contains);
```

For whatever reason, `Contains()` is not needed and this compiles just fine. I'm fairly inexperienced with the intricacies of LINQ, so I was wondering if anyone can answer or point me to an answer on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason `Contains` does not need the parentheses is because you are passing the function as the parameter to the `All` function and not the result of the function. If you look at the definition of [`All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netframework-4.7.2) you see:

```
public static bool All<TSource> (this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
                                 Func<TSource,bool> predicate);
```

'All' is expecting a `Func<TSource,bool>`. In this case `TSource` is `char` so `All` is expecting the given parameter to be a reference to a function that receives a character and returns a boolean - which is exactly what `Contains` does.

You could also write it the following way and it will result in the same output (but might look a bit more messy): (*For the difference see @pinkfloydx33's comment below*)

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".All(c => input.ToLower().Contains(c));
```

Comment: Difference between the two is that in the second example, `input.ToLower` will be called for each letter in the original string. In the first, the method group passed in (`Contains`) is bound to the instance returned by `input.ToLower()` which consequently only gets called once.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 - True. Good comment. I corrected accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should look at the input type.

Here, `All` method takes input: `Func<TSource, bool> predicate`

`All` method is: `public static bool All<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)`

And `Contains` method is: `public static bool Contains<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource value)`

Now, we see that the `Contains` method is a delegate that is same as `All` method input predicate.
So, we pass the `Contains` method as a delegate, not the output of `Contains` method through the `All` method.

So, we should write:

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".All(input.ToLower().Contains);
```

If we write : `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".All(input.ToLower().Contains());`
then it return bool as `All` method input, that must not work.

But if we want to use parentheses then you may use it in this way:

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".Contains(input)
```

Comment: `previously given answer.Contains(your answer)` returns `true`.